# Не могу передать параметр в Deep Link Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, deeplink

Всем привет, помогите пожалуйста с передачей параметра в deep link(уже все что можно и не можно перепробовал) - постоянно приходит просто ссылка без параметра.
"https://com.divinkas.example.customspinner"

Манифест:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data
                android:host="com.divinkas.example.customspinner"
                android:scheme="https"
                />
            <data
                android:host="com.divinkas.example.customspinner"
                android:scheme="http"
                />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Код как создаю и принимаю:

```
private void createDeepLink() {

    DynamicLink dynamicLink = FirebaseDynamicLinks
            .getInstance()
            .createDynamicLink()
            .setLink(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.link_app)+"?event=31"))
            .setDomainUriPrefix(getString(R.string.link_firebase))
            .setAndroidParameters(new 
     DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder().build())
            .setIosParameters(new DynamicLink.IosParameters.Builder(getString(R.string.app_name)).build())
            .buildDynamicLink();

    String link = dynamicLink.getUri().toString();
    textView.setText(link);
    Log.println(Log.INFO, "info deep", link);
}

private void getDeepLink() {
    FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
            .getDynamicLink(getIntent())
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, pendingDynamicLinkData -> {
                // Get deep link from result (may be null if no link is found)
                Uri deepLink;
                if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                    deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();
                    textView.setText(deepLink.getQueryParameter("event"));
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(this, e -> Log.w("Fail Link:", "getDynamicLink:onFailure", e));
}
```

Ссылки:

```
<string name="link_firebase">https://studenthelper.page.link/testLink</string>
<string name="link_app">https://com.divinkas.example.customspinner</string>
```

вот какая линка создается:
"https://studenthelper.page.link/testLink?apn=com.divinkas.example.customspinner&ibi=CustomSpinner&link=https%3A%2F%2Fcom.divinkas.example.customspinner%3Fevent%3D31"

Огромное спасибо заранее!)

Comment: Какой именно параметр?

Comment: в методе createDeepLink() я добавляю параметр event - в который передаю хардкором число 31

Comment: Ну а это: event%3D31 - параметр же? используй uri builder что бы избежать ошибок https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167954/use-uri-builder-in-android-or-create-url-with-variables

Comment: это как раз и параметр. Uri builder конвертирует точно такой же результат

Comment: Ну так и в чем проблема тогда?

Comment: в тому что когда мы нажимаем на ссылку и открывается наше приложение и в  метод getDeepLink() приходит приходит просто ссылка без параметра - который я пытаюсь передать

Comment: хз, вроде все норм. Попробуй еще так: <string name="link_firebase">https://studenthelper.page.link</string>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Саму ссылку нужно формировать вручную и устанавливать параметр первым, а потом уже апн и все другое.